# Which of these spaces is metrizable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

**The question:**

Which of the following topological spaces are metrizable?

1. Let $X$ be any non-empty set, and let the topology consist only of the empty set $\emptyset$ and the full space $X$.
2. Let $X$ be any infinite set, and let the topology consist of the empty set together with all subsets of $X$ whose complements are finite.
3. Let $X$ be the three-element set $\{a, b, c\}$, and let the topology consist of the following subsets of $X$: $\{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{a,b\}, \{a,c\}, X\}$.

(*Hint:* If a space is metrizable, then its open sets must have certain properties.)

**My answer and query:**

None of these seem to be metrizable. I am almost 100% sure that 1 cannot be metrizable. I think 2 isn't because I don't have any idea how to do it, and similarly for 3. However, I can't figure out the hint so I am not sure. Am I right or not?

(For reference, this is part of Problem 16-3 of *Introduction to Topology and Modern Analysis* by G.F. Simmons. The unquoted part of the question deals with obviously metrizable cases.)

Comment: A metrizable space has to be Hausdorff.

Comment: What do you make of the hint? Can you think of **any** topological properties a metric space must have? If you think of such a property then you can try to check whether your three problem spaces have that property.

Comment: @John - Thank you for your input. The definition of Hausdorff spaces appears on page 130 of this book and the above problem on page 94, so I don't think that is the property discussed.

Comment: Surely $X$ consisting of one point only is metrizable and satisfies point 1. in your question.

Comment: So you want to do that without using Hausdorff property of even $T_1$? Let me think.....

Comment: @SuzuHirose Surely this is about Hausdorffness, I don't see a way around it, point 2 is a classic example of a $T1$ space which is not $T2$. If you want to solve it without referring to Hausdorffness, just prove that in a metric space there are always two disjoint balls around each 2 different points and use this to prove nonmetrizability.

Comment: @user2345215 - I'm just reporting what the book says. Section 16 is the first section about topology, after a chapter about metric spaces. The discussion here has clarified to me why I found this confusing, since I didn't see what tools I had up to that point in the book to prove that these spaces were not metrizable. Probably the author wants people to guess (use intuition) since it covers the Hausdorff property later in the book. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given what you’re said in the comments, I think that you’re expected to realize that if $x$ and $y$ are distinct points in a metric space $\langle X,d\rangle$, and $0<\epsilon\le\frac12d(x,y)$, then $B(x,\epsilon)$ and $B(y,\epsilon)$ are disjoint open sets containing $x$ and $y$, respectively. (Later you’ll learn that spaces in which any two distinct points have disjoint open nbhds are called *Hausdorff* or $T_2$ spaces.)

This will allow you to rule out all three of the examples except for the special case of (1) in which $X$ has only one point; that special case *is* metrizable. You can write down the metric very easily: the only distance to be specified is $d(x,x)$, which must be ... ?

Actually, for (1) (when $X$ has more than one point) and (3) you really need only the fact that if $x\ne y$, and $0<\epsilon\le d(x,y)$, then $y\notin B(x,\epsilon)$, and for (2) you need only the fact that in any metric space with at least two points there are two disjoint non-empty open sets.

Answer (score 3):

Something to think about:

All metric spaces are Hausdorff (a.k.a T2) and as the Hausdorff property is a topological invariant you can check if a space is not metrizable by checking if it's not Hausdorff. For example, part (3) of your question:

For $ a,b \in X $ we cannot find two open sets $ U,V \subset X $ such that $ a \in U$ and $ b \in V $ with $ U \cap V = \emptyset $, because the only choices are $ \lbrace a \rbrace$ and $\lbrace a, b \rbrace $ with $ \lbrace a \rbrace \cap \lbrace a b \rbrace = \lbrace a \rbrace $ . Thus $ X $ is not Hausdorff and hence cannot be metrizable.

Be careful though, the converse is not true! Not all Hausdorff spaces are metric spaces, so if you find a space is Hausdorff you still have work to do if you want to show it's a metric space.